# Add padding to the input caret

Tags: html, css

Below is a snap of the input fields. Now, how can modify the input fields' caret to have certain padding so that users can start typing from the placeholder's position?
[Snap of input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjM0s.png). Below is my code snippet for the input fields:

```css
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0 0.375rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.form-control:focus {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #86b7fe;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code for these input fields instead of an image link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fix the `.form-control` `padding: 0.375rem 0 0.375rem 0;` so that it is for example `padding: 0.5rem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed the padding-left from .form-control::placeholder
and add it like this in the .form-control => padding: 0.375rem 0 0.375rem 10px;

Input padding also applies to the placeholder.

```css
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0 0.375rem 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.form-control:focus {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #86b7fe;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add padding to the placeholder, instead add padding to the input it'll automatically add same padding the placeholder and the text

```css
    .form-control {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0.375rem 0 0.375rem 0;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #212529;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      border: 1px solid #ced4da;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
      background-color: #fafafa;
      
      padding-left: 10px; // this is what i've changed
    }

    .form-control:focus {
      color: #212529;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-color: #86b7fe;
      outline: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
    }

    .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #6c757d;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .form-control::placeholder {
      color: #6c757d;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```